# How can I find / record the IP of a machine I SSH'd in from on, from the remote machine?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, login, logging

Is there a way I can log my logins on the remote machine when I SSH in to said remote machine? Though I'd only occasionally have a use for this, there are times when it'd be pretty handy (e.g. scp'ing a file back to my local machine, when the remote path is particularly long)?

The machine(s) in question are running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find `last -a` useful for this. Your accesses will also be logged in `/var/log/auth.log` (but by IP).

Comment: You can use `nslookup` or `host` to lookup the domain name of the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

```
whitequark@hagalaz:~$ ssh dagaz
Linux dagaz 2.6.26-2-686 #1 SMP Thu Sep 16 19:35:51 UTC 2010 i686
<skip>
whitequark@dagaz:~$ env | grep SSH
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.2.198 38427 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-omfqnn7365/agent.7365
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.2.198 38427 192.168.2.10 22
whitequark@dagaz:~$
```

The host can be extracted with following bashism:

```
$ echo ${SSH_CLIENT%% *}
192.168.2.198
```

or using sed, if you like:

```
$ sed -e "s/ .*$//" <<<$SSH_CLIENT
192.168.2.198
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `who am i` though i don't have a machine to test from.  I often use this to set DISPLAY.